# NullPointer Exception on reversing position of loop in reverse linked list 2

Tags: java, linked-list

Question
Given the head of a singly linked list and two integers left and right where left <= right, reverse the nodes of the list from position left to position right, and return the reversed list.

Constraints:

The number of nodes in the list is n.
1 <= left <= right <= n

code A(left after right)

```
class Solution {  
    public ListNode reverseBetween(ListNode head, int l, int r) {
        if(head == null || l == r || head.next == null)   return head;
        ListNode leftNode = head, rightNode = head, start = head, end = head;

        for(int i = 0; i < r-1; i++)    end = end.next;
                rightNode = end.next;
                end.next = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < l-2; i++)    leftNode = leftNode.next;
        start = leftNode.next;
        leftNode.next = null;

        

        start = reverse(start);
        leftNode.next = start;
        while(start.next!=null) start=start.next;
        start.next=rightNode;

        return  head;
    }
}


class Solution {

    public ListNode reverseBetween(ListNode head, int l, int r) {
        if(head == null || l == r || head.next == null)   return head;
        ListNode leftNode = head, rightNode = head, start = head, end = head;

        
        for(int i = 0; i < l-2; i++)    leftNode = leftNode.next;
        start = leftNode.next;
        leftNode.next = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < r-1; i++)    end = end.next;
        rightNode = end.next;
        end.next = null;

        start = reverse(start);
        leftNode.next = start;
        while(start.next!=null) start=start.next;
        start.next=rightNode;

        return  head;
    }
}
```

code B, same code but reverse the position of left and right loop

code does not compile and reaches null pointer exception in code B in end line , why is it so that it only gives that error in code B and why does it even give the error since both loop have nothing in common.

Comment: Java isn't Python. Loop bodies are not controlled by indentation. Use `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You write that your code does not compile, but it *does* compile -- provided you have defined `reverse` as a valid function. You can only get a null pointer exception when the code is being executed (implying it was compiled successfully).

The *second* version of your code will run into a null pointer exception because there you first break the list at position `l-1`, meaning that the list that starts at `head` no longer has `r` nodes, but has been clipped to `l-1` nodes. As in the second loop you still try to reach the `r`th node, you'll run into the `null` that you had assigned to `leftNode.next`, and in a next iteration of the same loop, you get the null pointer exception. Note that such issues can be spotted by running your code with a debugger.

This is a problem that your first code version does not have, as it first breaks the link at position `r`. As `l` is not greater than `r`, you'll still be able to locate position `l-1` to introduce the second break. There will be no null pointer exception.

You can fix the second version by moving the breaking of the list until after the second loop has finished. So move `end.next = null;` below the second loop, and it will no longer produce that same null pointer exception.

There is however still this issue (in both versions):

The code makes no distinction between the case where `l` is 1 and the case where it is 2. In both cases the second loop will not make iterations, so the result is the same. This obviously cannot be correct. There should be a difference. Notably when `l` is 1, and `r` is greater, you should not return the original `head`, because now the first node of the result list will be the first node of the *reversed* section.

Here is a (minimal) correction of the first version to also return the correct result when `l` is 1:

```
    public ListNode reverseBetween(ListNode head, int l, int r) {
        if (head == null || l == r || head.next == null) return head;
        ListNode leftNode = head,
                 rightNode, 
                 start = head, 
                 end = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < r-1; i++) end = end.next;
        rightNode = end.next;
        end.next = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < l-2; i++) leftNode = leftNode.next;
        // Don't update start when l is 1
        if (l > 1) start = leftNode.next;
        start = reverse(start);
        if (l > 1) { // Distinguish two cases
            leftNode.next = start;
        } else {
            head = start; // Update head when l was 1.
        }
        while (start.next != null) start = start.next;
        start.next = rightNode;

        return head;
    }
```

NB: You could optimise a bit by avoiding the loop at the end: you know which node needs to have its `next` set to `rightNode`: it is the `start` node *before* the reversal took place -- so save it, and use it for this assignment. Also the first two loops could be optimised: if you do the "left" loop first and don't update the list yet, the second one could continue from where the first one stopped instead of restarting from the head node (but be careful with the case where `l` is 1).